# Как начать две анимации одновременно?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть пример: [сайт](https://vostoksisters.github.io/) 
И иногда при его запуске анимация логотипа и анимация текста идет вразнобой (хотя кифреймы все выставлены одинаково). Чаще всего всё нормально. 
Можете посмотреть [репозиторий](https://github.com/VostokSisters/vostoksisters.github.io), если нужен код.

Можно начинать её при помощи js, тугглить класс когда загрузилась страница, и как только он затуглился, то анимация начнется.
Но можно ли как-нибудь без внедрения ещё каких-то классов? (тошно от их количества уже)

[image: vs]

Comment: Однако неплохо эффект при наведении. Только у меня немного висит, когда вся анимация происходит

Comment: @Yuri, в кеше всё должно быть, наверно. Если ты про телефон, то там просто забей, svg-кода там много. Всё работает раза в 3 легче, если не делать stroke к svg, но без него неклево.
Собственно это мой вообще первый сайт-то, учебное, по всему тому, что я за 3 месяца изучил, поэтому вопросов всяких много)

Comment: а где такому учат?

Comment: Дело в том, что если много анимаций запускается, то они могут забивать память пользователя и одна запускаться позже другой. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: @L.Vadim, там где нас нет )

Comment: @Yuri, вполне возможно. Я через тоннель с Browser Sync запускал на телефоне, там с каждой третьей перезагрузкой анимация текста не запускалась вообще. А в браузере Edge текст сразу же начинает мигать, а не анимироваться. Черт знает что :D Я не знаю, почему так плохо с анимацией текста...

Comment: @L.Vadim, учат чему?

Comment: делать такие анимашки

Comment: Попробуйте через Juqery анимацию сделать. Но мне кажется с Jquery ещё больше висеть будет)) Или как то эту надо переделать

Comment: @Yuri, а зачем мне jQuery? Там паттерны анимаций фиговые и черт знает как работают. Я как-то попробовал несколько примеров fade-in, fade-out и так далее, они вообще как-то странно работают. Так что вывод "при возникновении каких-то проблем, исправлять костыль на jQuery будет сложнее чем свои" возник в голове практически моментально.
Да ты и посмотри в sass мою анимацию, что там сложного такого? Цикл из нескольких цветов, идет анимация по кругу. И всё-то. Это касается анимации бекграунда, логотипа и надписи. Все остальное - transition. 3 анимации - и браузер уже не может? :D

Comment: @L.Vadim, да в интернете. У меня 100% самостоятельное обучение. Зайди на codepen, там куда круче анимашки делают чуваки.

Comment: thanks видел круто :)

Comment: @VostokSisters, чёрт его знает тогда. У меня под вечер голова не варит, так что даже не буду пытаться в код вникнуть) Может быть какая-та хрень в вашей анимации

Comment: @Yuri, да [вот](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/03/0001/0403/94611/11/c4af65647e.png) весь код, собственно-то. Чё вникать-то.

Comment: @VostokSisters, я глянул. Ваш сайт, когда запускается анимация, съедает у меня 25-40% ЦП

Comment: @Yuri, а что за компьютер у тебя? У меня никаких всплесков нагрузки.

Comment: @VostokSisters, 2010 года комп :D

Comment: @Yuri, ну тогда всё понятно.

Comment: @Yuri, [посмотри](https://vostoksisters.github.io/), пожалуйста, а теперь лагает? Я конвертировал все svg в png и убил много зайцев этим: скорость загрузки, производительность, неправильную отрисовку градиента в firefox, лагучесть анимации лого и текста (наверно, не знаю точно) и всякие неясные косяки с позиционированием свг. Как лучше стало?)

Comment: @VostokSisters, вроде бы неплохо )